# How to convert an integer array to a hex array that can be stored in a char array?

Tags: arrays, c, char, integer, hex

I would like to know how to convert an integer array into a hex array that can be stored into a char array such as the format below:

```
const unsigned char k[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C};
```

Below is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t a[] = {0, 10, 0, 0, 35, 45, 99, 100};
    const char k[sizeof(a)/sizeof(uint8_t)];
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(uint8_t);i++)
    {
        sprintf(k[i],"0x%X",a[i]); //Compile Error: Does not work because cannot store char* into char
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I searched online and I could not find any idea of how to convert an integer array into this specific hex char array (in this format) because I need to pass an array of this specific type to a function.

Comment: You need to `sprintf` into `k + i`, while `i` should progress by the number of characters already written (the return value of the previous `sprintf` call). Why is `k` defined as `const` BTW? Also it should be properly sized to contain the character representation of your array. It currently doesn't.

Comment: You don't need to use `sprintf()`, because (according to the example character array) you don't want _strings_ of "0xXX" but values that are _noted_ as hex. The hex notation is only important if a human reads a value as text. The single `uint8_t` values can be casted directly into `char`, for example like this: `k[i] = (char)a[i];` -- BTW, you cannot write into an array of `const char`. ;-) -- If this helps, I'll be glad to write an slightly extended real answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain if you are trying to have an array populated by strings which represent the hex values of the given integer or simply have an array of hex values. C has no native hexadecimal type and, if you store a hex value in a char array, it would be the same as storing an int inside the array (assuming the int was within the range -128 to 127). If you try to store something outside this range into a char, it won't work whether it's in hex or standard 10-base representation. However, if you want a array of strings in hex notation, you could do the following (assuming that the integers are less than 255. If you want to store larger ints, you have to increase the value of *m*):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdint.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int m = 2;
        uint8_t a[] = {0, 10, 0, 0, 35, 45, 99, 100};
        const char k[sizeof(a)/sizeof(uint8_t)][m+3];
        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(uint8_t); i++)
        {
            sprintf(k[i],"0x%X",a[i]);
            printf("%s\n", k[i]);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```